# Problems with div alignment and opacity

Tags: html, css, alignment, positioning

I'm trying to make a box with a link, which has a background with low opacity and two divs with different items. I've tried all the ways but I can't seem to get them properly aligned. Here's what I want to achieve, and my code.
[This is an image of what I want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoWZl.jpg)

Here's the code. 
https://jsfiddle.net/hmelluso/b3f2m2tb/

Comment: Edit the title of you question for something more descriptive with the question itself. Its turn more easier to other users help you.

Comment: Done! I think now that the point of the question becomes clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly this tag `<div class="redfooterh>` was missing the quote after the class name: `<div class="redfooterh">`

And some other settings to fine-tune, see here:

https://jsfiddle.net/4son84j9/2/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/b3f2m2tb/3/

You can just ad a relative background div to make opacity background.

```css
.redfooterw {
    max-width: 70rem;
    height: 7rem;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    justify-content: center;
    border-color: #eb1c2d;
}
.background{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fcc;
  opacity: 0.2
}
.inficon{
   width: 20%;
   z-index: 5;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}
.footerlink{
  text-align: left;
  width:80%;
   font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="redfooterw">
  <div class="background">
  </div>
      <div class="inficon"> &#128712;
      </div>
      <div class="footerlink ">
        <a href="# " target="_blank ">Para mayor información sobre este producto clic aquí.</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your quick answer, could you tell what am I doing wrong about the alignment of both elements?